# How to validate number fields with template driven forms in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, validation

Is there a way to validate the numerical value of input field using template driven forms in Angular 11?

To give a bit of context, I'm building a memory card game using Angular 11 and I'd like to make sure that the player can't select a maxFlipCount that is inferior to the number of cards. I have been struggling to make this work using the `min` attribute on an input tag. Maybe there's another that I don't know of that doesn't use the `min` attribute.

How could I achieve this?

I'm trying to apply this validation to the last input tag, before the submit button in my template code. This is what I have so far:

```html
<form #gameOptionsForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="startGame()" novalidate>
  <!-- mode de jeu -->
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Mode de jeu</label>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="select" [class.is-danger]="
          gameMode.invalid && (gameMode.dirty || gameMode.touched)
        ">
        <select name="gameMode" [(ngModel)]="optionsForm.gameMode" #gameMode="ngModel" required>
          <option value="1">1 joueur</option>
          <option value="2">2 joueurs</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="gameMode.invalid && (gameMode.dirty || gameMode.touched)">
      Vous devez choisir un mode jeu
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- nom du premier joueur -->
  <div class="field" *ngIf="optionsForm.gameMode == 1 || optionsForm.gameMode == 2">
    <label class="label">Nom du joueur 1</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input [class.is-danger]="
          player1.invalid && (player1.dirty || player1.touched)
        " class="input" type="text" name="player1" placeholder="Joueur 1" #player1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="optionsForm.player1" required />
    </div>
    <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="player1.invalid && (player1.dirty || player1.touched)">
      Veuillez entrer un nom pour le joueur 1
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- nom du deuxieme joueur -->
  <div class="field" *ngIf="optionsForm.gameMode == 2">
    <label class="label">Nom du joueur 2</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input [class.is-danger]="
          player2.invalid && (player2.dirty || player2.touched)
        " class="input" type="text" name="player2" placeholder="Joueur 2" #player2="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="optionsForm.player2" required />
    </div>
    <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="player2.invalid && (player2.dirty || player2.touched)">
      Veuillez entrer un nom pour le joueur 2
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- taille de la grille -->
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Nombre de cartes</label>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="select" [class.is-danger]="
          gridSize.invalid && (gridSize.dirty || gridSize.touched)
        ">
        <select name="gridSize" [(ngModel)]="optionsForm.gridSize" #gridSize="ngModel" required>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="16">16</option>
          <option value="36">36</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="gridSize.invalid && (gridSize.dirty || gridSize.touched)">
      Vous devez choisir un nombre de cartes
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- nombre maximal de coups -->
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Nombre maximal de coups</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input [class.is-danger]="
          maxFlipCount.invalid && (maxFlipCount.dirty || maxFlipCount.touched)
        " class="input" type="number" name="maxFlipCount" #maxFlipCount="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="optionsForm.maxFlipCount" required min="{{ optionsForm.gridSize }}" />
    </div>
    <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="
        maxFlipCount.invalid &&
        (maxFlipCount.dirty || maxFlipCount.touched) &&
        maxFlipCount.errors.required
      ">
      Veuillez entrer un nombre maximal de coups
    </p>
    <p class="help is-danger" *ngIf="maxFlipCount.errors?.min">
      Veuillez entrer un nombre supérieur ou égal à {{ optionsForm.gridSize }}
    </p>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!gameOptionsForm.form.valid">
    Commencer
  </button>
</form>
```

The `min` attribute does actually do it's job when I use the little arrows (automatically put there by the browser) on the side to increase/decrease the value, however the problem is when I type a value in manually, the field value can be whatever I want and it will not appear as being invalid.

Thank you for reading through this and suggesting any ideas.

Comment: What does this code do `#gameMode="ngModel"`?

Comment: Prefer `[min]="optionsForm.gridSize"`; this is probably where you issue comes from. You should not do the binding with accolades.

Comment: @Ploppy I've tried what you suggested, but nothing has changed. As for the `#gameMode` it is there to be able to reference the input field in the template code. For example, it allows me to access errors of that input field.

Comment: You don't have to set the value to `ngModel`, do you? Also I suggest you to replicate your issue on Stackblitz because I can't, it works for me.

Comment: The best way to do it is with a `Directive`, if you want to make sure the user can't type something. You can re-use the directive wherever you want.

Comment: @JorgeMussato I will look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer to my question. So, I used a custom directive to check that the value of the field was what I wanted.

This article explains it quite well: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-validation